# jQuery graph, chart custmization as per the inputs is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

Hi recently i tried Morris Area Charts , and it is good one  .  But the thing its difficult to understand how the data is fetched there .

I have seen the document https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html , & 
i make sample graph here

```js
 var data = [
          { y: '2014', a: 50, b: 90},
          { y: '2015', a: 65,  b: 75},
          { y: '2016', a: 50,  b: 50},
          { y: '2017', a: 75,  b: 60},
          { y: '2018', a: 80,  b: 65},
          { y: '2019', a: 90,  b: 70},
          { y: '2020', a: 100, b: 75},
          { y: '2021', a: 115, b: 75},
          { y: '2022', a: 120, b: 85},
          { y: '2023', a: 145, b: 85},
          { y: '2024', a: 160, b: 95}
        ],
        config = {
          data: data,
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
          labels: ['Total Income', 'Total Outcome'],
          fillOpacity: 0.6,
          hideHover: 'auto',
          behaveLikeLine: true,
          resize: true,
          pointFillColors:['#ffffff'],
          pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
          lineColors:['gray','red']
      };
    config.element = 'area-chart';
    Morris.Area(config);
```

```css
  #area-chart{
      min-height: 250px;
    }
```

```html
 <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Morris.js Area Chart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h3 class="text-primary text-center">
        Morris js charts
      </h3>
      <div class"row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <label class="label label-success">Area Chart</label>
          <div id="area-chart" ></div>
        </div>
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script> 
        
        
        
      </div>
    </body>
```

But i have different requirement now .

In Y axis i have to put year and in x axis and i have to show the following data in chart .

```
Initial  gain  total_gain  year
 100    10    110          1
 100    25    125          2
 200    20    220          1
 1200   180   1380         1
 1200   720   1920         3
```

But i don't know how i can i implement this in chart . If some one can understand how this work then please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getData` just transforms the original data into the right format so that there is no format-conflict with the current morris-chart-configuration (`xkey`, `ykeys`).

Although the most interesting part are `parseTime` and `xLabelFormat`. By setting `parseTime` `false` you tell this lib that you want the data not to be transformed into `Date`-objects. So you have more control of how to print the data onto the x-axis. Furthermore you can use `xLabelFormat` to actually print the data as you wish. In this examples the corresponding callback-function remembers the last `currentYear`-Number so that this number can be incremented by the next number.

```js
function getData(sets) {
    var result = [];
    sets.forEach(function(set) {
        result.push({
            y: set.year.toString(),
            a: set.Initial,
            b: set.Initial + set.gain
        });
    });
    return result;
}

var data = getData([{
            Initial: 100,
            gain: 10,
            year: 1
        },
        {
            Initial: 100,
            gain: 25,
            year: 2
        },
        {
            Initial: 200,
            gain: 20,
            year: 1
        },
        {
            Initial: 1200,
            gain: 180,
            year: 1
        },
        {
            Initial: 1200,
            gain: 720,
            year: 3
        },
    ]),
    config = {
        data: data,
        xkey: 'y',
        parseTime: false,
        xLabelFormat: function(y) {
            this.currentYear = this.currentYear ? (+this.currentYear) + (+y.label) : y.label;
            return this.currentYear;
        },
        ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
        labels: ['Total Income', 'Total Outcome'],
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        behaveLikeLine: true,
        resize: true,
        pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
        pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
        lineColors: ['gray', 'red']
    };
config.element = 'area-chart';
Morris.Area(config);
```

```css
#area-chart{
      min-height: 250px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Morris.js Area Chart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h3 class="text-primary text-center">
        Morris js charts
      </h3>
      <div class"row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <label class="label label-success">Area Chart</label>
          <div id="area-chart" ></div>
        </div>
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script> 
        
        
        
      </div>
    </body>
```

P.s.
I actually have made a function (`getData`) to build the `data` in the right format so that it does not conflict with the chart-configuration. So when you want to change the chart-config you have to change `getData` as well.

I have also provided a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blauharley/f4e5jk1L/15/#&togetherjs=Tp3zvA6Jlg) to show of how you can still zoom into this morris-chart by taking advantage of resize-events. In this example the chart will split up into two charts when you zoom in.

Comment: thank you friend . But in x  axis's i need year (like 1 year , 2 year etc )

Comment: Something like this? As soon as you accept this answer, I'll put some explanation in it.

Comment: Do you have some controll over the passed data? Or can you change the year property?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you have to increment the x-axis (year) after each data-entry? But you can print the x-axis by using xLabelFormat-function

Comment: can we reduce the gap between y axsis ?instead of 500 difference can we make it as 50 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is no option to define a y-axis steps (gaps) between the data-points but you can leave out some bigger data-samples (1380, 1920) to "zoom into" the graph. Nice question!

Comment: Because of your cool question I provided a fiddle example for this gap-problem in my answer. Have fun!